# How to implement entity validation across instances of the same entity

Tags: c#, validation, entity, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

In our project we use DDD as architecture (clean architecture).
Let's say I have an entity called A. A has a property called B.
Now I want a validation that when a second entity A is created, that B must be unique over all instances of A in a store.

My idea was to implement a domain service for it, using the repository. The question then is if this domain service should implement the validation itself or just provide that data for it... (to be used in the interactor/usecase for validation).

Example code (code is kept simple):

```
public class A
{
   public A(string b)
   {
      B = b;
   }

   public string B {get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: To be honest, what you displayed is not `clean` at all :) your model has a constructor.

But regardless of a POV debate, this work is best delegated to an underlying framework. E.g. if coding against a memory store, create a `Dictionary<string, object>` and just add keys for all values of `B`. Dictionaries in c# don't allow duplicate keys. If coding against a db, implement a unique constraint. If storing in flat files, make this a job of a class that writes actual files.

Comment: Having a constructor not clean? Why isn’t that clean? It is the best way to create an object with all the neccessary (required fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a domain service is the option to take, take a look at this blog(blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2017/08/23/…) where the 'username must be unique' scenario is given, resembling my issue in the initial post.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say I have an entity called A. A has a property called B. Now I want a validation that when a second entity A is created, that B must be unique over all instances of A in a store.

The problem you are trying to solve is sometimes known as [set validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).

The easy answer: you introduce an index, that tracks the mapping of each value B to the specific entity A that is allowed to own it.

Of course, that introduces contention; you'll need to mitigate the case where two different A's are being modified at the same time.  The index, and *all* of the A's, become part of a single consistency boundary that needs to be managed.  This is pretty much what happens when we are storing our entites in a single RDBMS -- we can introduce a constraint to ensure that there are no duplicates.

You can split that single consistency boundary into separate A entities, and also individual B->A entities.  But now you have the possible problem of trying to modify two different consistency boundaries at the same time, and that introduces race conditions.

A third possibility is to relax the consistency constraint -- allow conflicts to be stored, and resolve them later.  See, for example, Greg Young on [warehouse systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=10m48s) and Udi Dahan on [race conditions](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/).

The usual answer from [domain-driven-design](/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design) is to push back really hard on that requirement, to make sure that it is real: what's the actual cost to the business if the constraint is violated?

Think airplane seat maps: obviously only one passenger should be sitting in a seat.  But that doesn't mean it's a critical failure for the seat to be *assigned* to more than one person, because the human operators (gate agents) have ways of mitigating these problems.  See also Greg Young's talk [Stop Over Engineering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRr4xeMn1uU).

Comment: This pretty much covers all the options.  I would suggest that problems should be sorted sooner rather than later.  It is going to be about the customer experience (UX or real life).  I'd rather be notified of a seating issue while I'm sitting in front of my computer than at the airport :P --- if it isn't going to be an issue adding a unique index/constraint then go that route.  If you **do** *temporarily* allow a violation then you should attempt to resolve it as soon as possible.  For instance, there could be a validation step right after the initial capture.